# How can I attach a label to a scrollview in Basic4Android?

Tags: basic4android

How can I attach a label to a scrollview at design time (not in the designer)
So I can create a label but the content of my 100% widthx 100% height
label, the long text goes off the screen.  Is there a simple way to make the
label scroll without getting too complex?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I exactly understand your question. You should put the label on a ScrollView in order to make it scrollable.
A tutorial about ScrollView is available [here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/showthread.php?p=38619).

You can use StringUtils.MeasureMultilineTextHeight to calculate the required height.